# Ошибка с преобразованием

Tags: c++, указатели, преобразование-типов

При вызове этой функции компилятор выдает ошибку

(не существует подходящего конструктора для преобразования из point(*)[20] в point).

```
int amount_of_alive_neighbours(point playground[_HEIGHT_][_WIDTH_], int x, int y)
{
    int count = 0;
    int neighbours[8][2];
    int _x, _y;

    neighbours_coordinates(neighbours, x, y);

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        _x = neighbours[i][0];
        _y = neighbours[i][1];

        if (_x < 0 || _y < 0)
            continue;
        if (_x >= _WIDTH_ || _y >= _HEIGHT_)
            continue;

        if (playground[_x][_y].alive)
            count++;
    }

    return count;
}
```

Вызываю так:

```
alive_neighbours = amount_of_alive_neighbours(previous_playground, i, j);
```

point - структура

```
struct point
{
bool alive:true;
}
```

Откуда вызываю функцию:

```
void next_playground(point new_playground[_WIDTH_][_HEIGHT_], point previous_playground[_WIDTH_][_HEIGHT_])
{
    int alive_neighbours;
    point pg;

    for (int i = 0; i < _WIDTH_; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < _HEIGHT_; j++)
        {
            pg = previous_playground[i][j];
            alive_neighbours = amount_of_alive_neighbours(previous_playground, i, j);
        }
}
```

Ниже краткий пример законченного кода

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
#define _HEIGHT_ 20
#define _WIDTH_ 20

struct point
{
    bool alive : true;
};

int amount_of_alive_neighbours(point playground[_HEIGHT_][_WIDTH_], int x, int y)
{
    return 1;
}

void next_playground(point new_playground[_WIDTH_][_HEIGHT_], point previous_playground[_WIDTH_][_HEIGHT_])
{
    int alive_neighbours;
    point pg;

    for (int i = 0; i < _WIDTH_; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < _HEIGHT_; j++)
        {
            pg = previous_playground[i][j];
            alive_neighbours = amount_of_alive_neighbours(previous_playground, i, j); //ERROR
        }
    }

int main()
{
    point pg1[_WIDTH_][_HEIGHT_];
    point pg2[_WIDTH_][_HEIGHT_];
    next_playground(pg1, pg2);
}
```

Comment: Покажите, как объявлена `previous_playground`, и, желательно, покажите ошибку компилятора *дословно*.

Comment: Ошибка дословно написана выше. Номер - E0415

Comment: Как определены `_HEIGHT_` и `_WIDTH_`? В какой именно строке ошибка?

Comment: Они определены так: `#define _HEIGHT_ 20` и `#define _WIDTH_ 20`. Строку с ошибкой я выделил над описанием структуры (где вызываю функцию `amount_of_alive_neighbours`), она последняя перед закрывающими скобками в функции `next_playground`

Comment: Вы не могли бы написать короткий код, который воспроизводит эту  же самую ошибку? Чтобы мы могли скомпилировать его сами и повторить ее. Не по частям, а законченный код. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @HolyBlackCat добавил

Comment: Почитайте, пожалуйста, о том, как правильно предоставить [mcve] в вопросе.

Comment: Вы что-то выдумываете. Такой ошибки в этом коде нет и быть не может. Приведенный вами код не соответствует действительности. Приводите реальный код.

Comment: Все компилируется: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/87c8c19b2ee59cb9 (куча варнингов не считается)

Comment: Отдельное недоумение вызывает ваше `bool alive : true;` Возможно вы не совсем понимаете, что именно делает эта конструкция.

Answer (score -1):

Массивы с фиксированным размером в c++ передаются только по ссылке:

```
int foo(int (& array)[2][4]){
   return sizeof(array);
}

int bar(){
    int array[2][4];
    return foo(array);
}
```

Или можно преобразовать в двойной указатель и передавать размер отдельно.

Лучше использовать `std::array` для таких массивов.

Comment: Ну нет. Почему обязательно ссылка? Вот [пример](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1fc1b868738a1007) - никакой ссылки нет, но все работает.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat я не знаю, почему это компилируется, но тип аргумента уже не является типом массива фиксированного размера. [пример](https://godbolt.org/g/NVv6TM)

Comment: А почему это не должно компилироваться? Когда вы пытаетесь использовать массив (вида `T name[N]` или `T name[]`) как параметр функции, компилятор автоматически заменяет его тип на `T *name`. Для двумерных массивов нет никаких особых правил, потому что они по сути являются массивами массивов. Потом, когда вы пытаетесь передать массив в такой параметр, то он превращается в указатель по тем же правилам, автоматически.

Comment: Раз пример по моей ссылке компилируется, значит у автора вопроса какая-то другая проблема, но какая...

Comment: Изменил функцию в соответствии с примером `int amount_of_alive_neighbours(point (&playground)[_HEIGHT_][_WIDTH_], int x, int y)`, но ошибка осталась

Comment: UPDATE: изменил вызов функции на такой: `alive_neighbours = amount_of_alive_neighbours(**previous_playground, i, j);`, а саму функцию на такую: `int amount_of_alive_neighbours(point *playground[_HEIGHT_][_WIDTH_], int x, int y); ..... if ((*playground)[_x][_y].alive)
   count++;`. Теперь выдаёт такую ошибку: [скриншот](http://prntscr.com/joqlnq)

Comment: @Ariox: "Или можно преобразовать в двойной указатель..." - это как это вы собрались преобразовывать массив `[][]` в двойной указатель?

Comment: @Ariox: "но тип аргумента уже не является типом массива фиксированного размера..." - и пусть не является. Никто не говорил, что он должен им являться. Никакого требования передачи по ссылке не существует.

Comment: @patrikmister: Перестаньте заниматься бессмысленными изменениями, а сначала приведите осмысленное описание исходной проблемы. Никакой ошибки в том, что вы пока наприводили, нет.